# Display Data from Firestore using Cardview

Tags: android, firebase, android-cardview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from Firestore then display it using a `CardView`.
It seems to get all the necessary code in, but when I run the app, no data is displayed. The app runs without crashing. I can't figure out where the problem is.
I'd be very grateful if someone could show me what I'm missing or where the wrong is.

[image]

Main Activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    RestaurantAdapter.OnRestaurantSelectedListener {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


// FireStore
@BindView(R.id.recycler_restaurants)
RecyclerView mRestaurantsRecycler;

private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
private Query mQuery;

private RestaurantAdapter mAdapter;


// FireStore END


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    // Enable Firestore logging
    FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);

    // Firestore
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    // Get ${LIMIT} restaurants
    mQuery = mFirestore.collection("restaurants")
            .limit(5);


    // RecyclerView
    mAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(mQuery, this);


    mRestaurantsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRestaurantsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Start listening for Firestore updates
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }

}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


@Override
public void onRestaurantSelected(DocumentSnapshot restaurant) {

}
```

Restaurant Adapter

```java
public class RestaurantAdapter extends FireStoreAdapter<RestaurantAdapter.ViewHolder> {


public interface OnRestaurantSelectedListener {

    void onRestaurantSelected(DocumentSnapshot restaurant);

}


private OnRestaurantSelectedListener mListener;


public RestaurantAdapter(Query query, OnRestaurantSelectedListener listener) {
    super(query);
    mListener = listener;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_restaurant, parent, false));
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
}


static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    @BindView(R.id.restaurant_item_name)
    TextView nameView;

    @BindView(R.id.restaurant_item_description)
    TextView descriptionView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                     final OnRestaurantSelectedListener listener) {

        Restaurant restaurant = snapshot.toObject(Restaurant.class);


        nameView.setText(restaurant.getName());
        descriptionView.setText(restaurant.getDescription());


        // Click listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onRestaurantSelected(snapshot);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Recycler:

```xml
<!-- Main Restaurants recycler -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_restaurants"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_restaurant"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

CardView:

```xml
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_item_name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_item_description"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="italic"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: your `onActivityResult` is empty should there be anything there?

Comment: For future visitors, you can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)**, where I have explained step by step how to display data from Firestore into a `RecyclerView` using Android.

Comment: I've moved into using React Native for creating this app instead. It seems to be a lot lot easier !!! Especially for this particular part! & you write the one lot of code that then makes an android app & iOS app out of the one code base.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set debug breakpoints. I think you're calling

```
mAdapter.startListening()
```

before the adapter is instantiated.

Try removing it from onStart() and put after the adapter setup.
If results starts to come, refactor your code as you prefer.