# How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to display data from an existing Firestore database in a `RecyclerView` using Android?

This isn't covered as a full explanation in an answer, so I've added this Q&A-style so it can be linked to in comments.

Comment: Isn't there a decent example of this on another site?

Comment: @AndréKool I didn't find a fully explained example of how to display data using Android.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming you have a Firestore database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- products (collection)
           |
           --- documentIdOne (document)
           |        |
           |        --- productName: "Milk"
           |
           --- documentIdTwo (document)
           |        |
           |        --- productName: "Soy Milk"
           |
           --- documentIdThree (document)
                    |
                    --- productName: "Bacon"
```

A model class that looks also like this:

```
public class ProductModel {
    private String productName;

    public ProductModel() {}

    public ProductModel(String productName) {this.productName = productName;}

    public String getProductName() {return productName;}
}
```

And a `.XML` file that contains a `RecyclerView` which also looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
```

To display all the product names, please follow the next steps.

First, you need to find the `RecyclerView` in your activity and set the `LinearLayoutManager` like this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Then you need to create the root reference of your Firestore database and a `Query` object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("products")
        .orderBy("productName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Then you'll have to create a `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object like this:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ProductModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductModel>()
        .setQuery(query, ProductModel.class)
        .build();
```

In your activity class, create a `holder` class that looks like this:

```
private class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;

    ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }

    void setProductName(String productName) {
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(productName);
    }
}
```

Then create an `adapter` which is declared as global:

```
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ProductModel, ProductViewHolder> adapter;
```

And instantiate it in your activity like this:

```
adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ProductModel, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder productViewHolder, int position, @NonNull ProductModel productModel) {
        holder.setProductName(productModel.getProductName());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }
};
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the end, don't forget to override the following two methods and start listening for changes:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to display a toast message when the user clicks on an item, please add the following lines of code inside the `setProductName()` method from the `ProductViewHolder` class:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm doing a nested query to first populate the list with Orders and populate OrderProducts for each order inside 

```android
onBindViewHolder
```
,

It is working but there are performance issues and is jittery.
What would you suggest is the right way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: @fuadj Without seeing your code I cannot be much of a help. So please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me or other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: One final thing would be to add
```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

Comment: @AlexMamo how can I implement pagination within your above code

Comment: @VikashSharma You can try this [solution](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorepagingadapter). Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried your suggestions and got the result for the pagination but it started janking the UI while scrolling. As I am working on a Chat App, I need to apply the pagination while scrolling towards the top. Could you suggest to me how can I achieve this as I didn't find the relevant information?