# Firestore : after getting data from firestore and get the values from object and add it to listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object data structure like below:

[image]

These is the code I have retreived the document data:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("Split").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("SentInvitations").document(documentId);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());

                        Object value = document.getData();// Here I added the data to the object type value 
                        System.out.println("values"+ value);


                        } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

I have retreived these data from Firestore database. Now I need amount, phone Number and Status in all the Invite(1,2) and add into the list view .
I am not able to get these fields first . After that I need to add them to list view . And also whenever user update field Status  then listview should also update.

Comment: check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: this is not my question after retrieving document data and I need to get the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `docRef` DocumentReference is correct, to get the values of `Amount`, `PhoneNumber` and `Status` properties, please change the following lines of code:

```
Object value = document.getData();// Here I added the data to the object type value 
System.out.println("values"+ value);
```

to

```
String amount = document.getString("Amount");
String phoneNumber = document.getString("PhoneNumber");
String status = document.getString("Status");
System.out.println(amount + " / " + phoneNumber + " / " + status);
```

Let's assume you want to get the values of the properties for your Invite1 documents, the output will be:

```
10 / 9876543210 / Pending
```

**Edit:** According  to your comment, I understand that you want to get the values of those properties from all documents but in your code you are using the following reference, that points to a single document and not to the entire collection.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db
    .collection("deyaPayUsers")
    .document(mAuth.getUid())
    .collection("Split")
    .document(mAuth.getUid())
    .collection("SentInvitations")
    .document(documentId); //Reference to a document
```

See, the last method that is called is `.document(documentId)`? To get all documents, you need to use a `CollectionReference`. So please use the following code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db
    .collection("deyaPayUsers")
    .document(mAuth.getUid())
    .collection("Split")
    .document(mAuth.getUid())
    .collection("SentInvitations").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                String amount = map.get("Amount").toString();
                String phoneNumber = map.get("PhoneNumber").toString();
                String status = map.get("Status").toString();
                System.out.println(amount + " / " + phoneNumber + " / " + status);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be:

```
10 / 9876543210 / Pending
20 / 1234566789 / Pending
```

**Edit2:**

```
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : m.entrySet()) {
                        s.append(e.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, s.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be:

```
10 9876543210 Pending
20 1234566789 Pending
//And so on
```

Comment: I need to get from all the Invites in a document. I need a loop and to store it in variable and add it to the listview

Comment: I have Known the documentId no need to use the QuerySnapshot

Comment: If you are using the reference in your code, you can get **only** one document, the document with that particular id that is used in your reference `.document(documentId)`. There is no way in which you can loop through other documents using that reference. The **only** way in which you can get the data within all documents is as in my updated answer. So using `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is mandatory, right?

Comment: I dont want to loop other documents .In one document I have many invites I want to loop these invites and get the values

Comment: You are not explaining the problem very clearly. To have a quick solve, please add your read database structure and indicate the exact value that you want to get. A screenshot would be enough.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. In the above  screenshot there are many Invitees and it contain fields . Now I need to get all the fields from all invitees and add those values to list view. but I am not aware of How to get those values

Comment: Now it is more clear. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: K I WILL check it

Comment: How can we take each status into an variable

Comment: In that case, you should consider create a custom adapter. If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)** is how you can retrieve data from a Cloud Firestore database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: How csn we get each field into an variable

Comment: just like this "String a = document.getString("PhoneNumber")" . how can I get

Comment: In the same way as explained in that post. Don't forget also to add more views to hold the values.

Comment: This question was for Android. You need to post another question for ios.

Comment: its ok kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve above like below and as per your comments you have your document id then

```
Invite invite = document.toObject(Invite.class).withId(document.getId());

public class Invite {

    private int amount;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String status;


    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnot understand your answer

Comment: I have only one document in that document I need to get the values

Comment: You need to use QuerySnapshot to get your data from firestore and convert it to your model class.

Comment: Why I need to use QuerySnapshot I know the document id

Comment: if you have document id then you can get the single object like 

AutoCheckIn checkIn = document.toObject(AutoCheckIn.class).withId(document.getId());

Comment: In model class what I need to write

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170340/discussion-between-vijju-and-riddhi-shah).