# What is the best way to update many TextView with Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, textview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to everything, so have mercy.

So for my first app I wanted to do a simple scoreboard app for the upcoming world cup. I used a `TableLayout` and put `TextViews` in each row (for example Pts, Wins etc.). I've set everything to 0 for the time except names. There are around 280 TextViews. Now to update the stats from my PC Firestore seems to be the best choice.

How can I update every TextView efficiently? It would take too much time to write down the code for every data piece (assign string, setText etc.)

Comment: You create a model, you create instance of list of your model, you create listview adapter, and then feed that adapter to the listview. Then firebase/firestore takes of everything.. **[`Here's a video tutorial for you`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyGVgrLG3KU)**

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding you correctly , you are saying that you have 280 textViews in TableLayout. I would recommend using the recyclerview for this since its much more efficient and dynamic compared to TableLayout. Here is a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you elaborate in which way it can solve the problem? You don't have to go into detail.  That's how the app looks like btw: https://imgur.com/a/KDUK0Zo Every text is a textview, which makes it too hard to update via Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid displaying so many views which are not recycled because you'll end up having very slow app. I also recommend you using a `RecyclerView` and for that, if you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)** is how you can retrieve data from a Cloud Firestore database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`.