# I want to save a same string in my all documents of a collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a application using Firestore in this app I want to save a same string in all documents of a collection in one click

For Example: See in the image. I have created a collection name `Links`. In this Collection I have created many Documents.

So I want to save string `field: name` and `value:anyname`, in all documents in one click on press button.
How it's possible? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
CollectionReference linksRef = rootRef.collection("Links");
linksRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("propertyName", "propertyValue");
                placesRef.document(document.getId()).update(map);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

All your documents will have now a new `propertyName` property that will hold the value of `propertyValue`.