# Insert a new document in all collection documents

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Hello friends i have created an application using firestore, in this application i have created a collection named Users and in this collection i have created many documents and in each document i have created a collection Notification. Now I want to add a new document in Notification collection in my all documents of Users collection on pressing a button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDNGw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RczVN.png)

Comment: I have answered you this **[I want to save a same string in my all documents of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656878/i-want-to-save-a-same-string-in-my-all-documents-of-a-collection)** question and you deleted it. I'm afraid that someone will try to reponde to your question knowing that he'll spend some time for helping you and as a response to his efforts, you'll delete the question again :|

Comment: Sorry for that i have deleted the question because the question i asked is wrong so i deleted

Comment: Your question was not wrong. Beside that, it's a common issue when it comes to NoSql databases. I'd appreciate it fi you'll restore the question and and you'll take an action about that answer.