# retrieve subcollection documents from firebase firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve subcollection documents from firebase firestore android and show it in recycler view but nothing is showing in recycler view I think have a problem in data retrieving

```
 var myarray=ArrayList<User>()
   rv=findViewById(R.id.idrecycler) as? RecyclerView
    notebookRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
           for(uid in querySnapshot!!.documentChanges){
               uid.document.reference.collection("ProfileData")
                   .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot2, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                   for(da in querySnapshot2!!){
                  val note = da.toObject(Note::class.java)
                       var title = note.title
                  var description = note.notes
                           var note2 = da.toObject(Note2::class.java)
                           var username = note2!!.username
                           myarray.add(User(username!!,str.child(currentuser),title!!,description!!))
                       }
              }
  }}
```

User.class

```
data class User(
    var username:String,
    var userphoto: StorageReference,
    var title:String,
    var notes:String
)
```

uid are UserUID
da are id of some notes

Database Snapshot :

[image]

Comment: Please post the database snapshot to understand your question.

Comment: The way your trying to retrieve the subcollection documents won't work as you expected. I suggest you to retrieve the documents list then onClick on document send to new activity then retrieve the data of subcollection documents

Comment: can you explain more, I edited database snapshot

Comment: whose data you want to retrieve it depends on it. If you want to retrieve all the user. Then i provide help according the situation.

Comment: yes all the data users

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295289/10182897 try this answer

Comment: but I use firebase firestore cloud

Comment: First you have to retrieve the users list and show it in recyclerview

Comment: you mean I have to store UserUID in Realtime and show their data from firestore

Comment: nope you have to retrieve all the users then onclick of each user. You can retrieve values from Subcollection

Comment: how can I retrieve users than their data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746587/display-data-from-firebase-firestore-to-recyclerview-with-kotlin rest depend on you sir

Comment: I can t retrieve useruid > profiledata > data can you help me