# Retreiving data from firebase using android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebaseui

[How can I retreive data in from firebase In recycler view using firebase UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3gcc.png)

I am in middle of an important Project can anyone please help me with this. I am not so familiar with kotlin. So if any one could please help .

Comment: Please check official Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tired already. It might spark up the conversation. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are beginning, so would be nice check out firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write... then let us know how are you progressing

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746587/display-data-from-firebase-firestore-to-recyclerview-with-kotlin/51746993)** out.