# How to show circular progressBar with firestoreRecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using `FirestoreRecyclerView` in my app. I want to show `ProgressBar` while
`FirestoreRecyclerView` loading data and if there is not data to show in `RecyclerView` then show `TextView` which has text "no data found". If there data to show then hide both `TextView` and `ProgressBar` and show data in `RecyclerView`.Please guide how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two layouts as the child of the main layout.
The first layout contains both `TextView` and `ProgressBar` and its visibility is set to `visible`.

The second layout then is the `FirestoreRecyclerView` which is set to `invisible` or `gone`.

As soon as your code receives data for that RecyclerView, hide the first layout and make the RecyclerView visible.

Here's an example:

**MainLayout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- the progress layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_progress"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading data"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FirestoreRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/firestoreRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
//...
//When we received all the data to display in recyclerView, do this
layout_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
firestoreRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to use recyclerview like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android