# How to get data from cloud firestore and display it with recycler view

Tags: java, android

I have a cloud firestore database with a collection named Bus and three documents inside it as it is shown in the image 
[database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GuqF.jpg)
I have followed what is written in this link 
[How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android)

three recycler views are being created and displayed but with empty data 
also when I add a fourth document to Bus  four recycler views are being created and displayed but with empty data

can you tell me how to fix my code?

model:

```
public class Bus {
    public Bus(String driverName, int busNo, String contactNo) {
        this.driverName = driverName;
        this.busNo = busNo;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public Bus(){ }
    public String getDriverName() {
        return driverName;
    }

    public void setDriverName(String driverName) {
        this.driverName = driverName;
    }

    public int getBusNo() {
        return busNo;
    }

    public void setBusNo(int busNo) {
        this.busNo = busNo;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    String driverName, contactNo;
    int busNo ;
}
```

activity code :

```
public class ViewBusDetailes   extends AppCompatActivity  {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Bus, BusViewHolder> adapter;
    class BusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private View view;

        BusViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }

        void setDetiles(String contactNoText , String driverNameText, int busNoText) {
            TextView driverName;
            TextView busNo;
            TextView contactNo;
            driverName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.driverNameDriverListView);
            contactNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.driverContactDriverListView);
            busNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.busNumber);
            driverName.setText(driverNameText);
            busNo.setText(String.valueOf(busNoText));
            contactNo.setText(contactNoText);
        }
    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_bus_details__layout);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query query = rootRef.collection("Bus");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Bus> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Bus>()
                .setQuery(query, Bus.class)
                .build();


        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Bus, BusViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Bus model) {
                holder.setDetiles(model.getContactNo() , model.getDriverName() ,model.getBusNo());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BusViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bus_list_view, parent, false);
                return new BusViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

bus_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/busNumber"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverNameDriverListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="#de000000"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:text="Anwar"

            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverContactDriverListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="#de000000"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:text="Dude can you solve this problem plea..."

            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_view_bus_detiels.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ViewBusDetailes"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Remove all getter setter from bus Model

Comment: I would say, first go through documentation before starting - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @GaneshPokale I removed setters and it  did not work

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
public class Bus {
    private String driverName;
    private int busNo;
    private String contactNo;

    public String getDriverName() {
        return driverName;
    }

    public int getBusNo() {
        return busNo;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }
}
```

activity code :

```
public class ViewBusDetailes extends AppCompatActivity  {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    class BusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView driverName;
        TextView busNo;
        TextView contactNo;

        BusViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            driverName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.driverNameDriverListView);
            contactNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.driverContactDriverListView);
            busNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.busNumber);
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_bus_details__layout);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query query = rootRef.collection("Bus");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Bus> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Bus>()
                .setQuery(query, Bus.class)
                .build();


        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Bus, BusViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Bus model) {

                holder.driverName.setText(model.getDriverName());
                holder.busNo.setText(String.valueOf(model.getBusNo()));
                holder.contactNo.setText(model.getContactNo());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BusViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(ViewBusDetailes.this).inflate(R.layout.bus_list_view, parent, false);
                return new BusViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, add this dependency if you haven't.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.2'
```

Also, edit your Firebase Firestore rules from Firestore settings in the firebase console.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Check if it works.

Comment: It did not work I also need setters because i am adding buses in another activity

Comment: setters shouldn't be a problem. Can you post the XML layouts of the activity and the recyclerview item

Comment: Looks like there's nothing wrong in layouts. Try to copy paste the activity code. It's adjusted to match yours.

Comment: Did you granted the permissions on the firebase console to access your data? Edited the post. Check the firestore rules.

Comment: I still have the problem the firestore rules read, write are true

Comment: Post a logcat when opening this activiy