# Is it possible to implement FirebaseRecycler in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I am building an app with a similar layout as Venmo where there are three ViewPagers (Home, Friends, Public) that each display data from Firebase in a continuously updating view. My initial idea was to use a RecyclerView from the FirebaseUI library but several questions related to mine say that this is not possible since Firebase does not work well with fragments. I was wondering if this was still the case as the questions were several years old.

I already have the ViewPager set up and working properly and even have a RecyclerView populated with CardViews. However, they are not getting data from Firebase. I was using this SO answer to try and acheive my goal [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842#49277842) but ran into a problem when implementing the FirebaseRecyclerOptions object. This code is inside my onCreateView method of my fragments:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setQuery(query,Post.class)
                .build();
```

The error that I am getting is "Cannot resolve method 'setQuery()."

I assume that the issue is Post.class cannot be called in a fragment but I am unsure how else to call it. I may be doing this in the completely wrong way but appreciate any help.

Comment: Please explain any down votes so that I may make any clarifications. I have looked through several other questions and have found none that get to the heart of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. As I was following the linked question above I got to this line of code:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setQuery(query,Post.class)
                .build();
```

This wasn't working for me and was giving error that it Could not resolve FirestoreRecyclerOptions but I was unable to find out why. Turns out I was missing:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
```

In my build.Gradle.