# Need help in retrieving hash map values from Firestore (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble retrieving hash map values from Firestore. I have no trouble in uploading the values, but I am having difficulty in retrieving them.
[image: Here is my Firestore database.]

Here are my constructors:

```
public class OrderItems {
    private String uid;
    private String product;
    private int qty;
    private int price;
    private int totalPrice;

    public OrderItems(){

    }

    public OrderItems(String uid, String product, int qty, int price) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.product = product;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {
        return qty * price;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(int totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }
}
```

My hash map constructor:

```
public class OrderObject {

    private HashMap<String, OrderItems> orders;

    public OrderObject(){

    }

    public OrderObject(HashMap<String, OrderItems> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public HashMap<String, OrderItems> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
}
```

How do I store the objects using a constructor through an array list? And how can I access the individual fields afterwards? Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, there are no errors, but I am receiving null values when I try to place it in my recycler view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your DocumentSnapshot to HashMap

```
db.collection("Deliveries").document("your_document_id").get()
.addOnSuccessListener {
val obj = it.get("Coconut") as HashMap<*, *>
Log.d("TAG",   it.get("Coconut").toString())
// This will print the whole map value
Log.d("TAG", obj.get("qty").toString())
}.addOnFailureListener {}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are storing `OrderItems` objects within a single document. If you attach a listener on a particular object, the object that is returned is  of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot):

> A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Firestore database. The data can be extracted with the getData() or get() methods.

If you intend to use [getData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()), a `Map` object is returned, so you can simply iterate over it and get the desired data. But remember, you cannot get directly a list of `OrderItems` objects, you need to write code for that.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but in your case, a more appropriate solution would be to store those items as separate documents in a collection. In this way you can get all documents (OrderItems objects) within an order collection and display them in a `RecyclerView`, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)

**Edit:**

If you need to map an array of custom objects into a list, please check the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: StackOverflow community should remove this answer because author of this answer has posted link to PAID article, not an answer. This is not the answer.