# Firestore Recycler adapter - multiple view types

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a chat activity that will use data from Firestore database and display messages in two different layouts.

For that I'm gonna need an `adapter` with multiple view types. Tried using a single view type and hiding `TextViews` and it resulted in display problems in the app.

I found solutions to create such an adapter for either Firebase Realtime Database or javascript, but I can't find any for Firestore Database and Java using Android Studio. How should I proceed?

Comment: The key to solving this issue is to use [two different layouts](https://github.com/alexmamo/Firestore-ChatApp/blob/74ffafa07c7b4faca30ce94f113eb51802068769/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/chatapp/activities/ChatActivity.kt#L98). Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Is there a way to convert such Kotlin code/project to Java? My whole project is in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`swapAdapter`?

Basically set a simple a simple firestore and all the required instances like `RecyclerView` , `Model` , `ViewHolder` , `adapter1` , `adapter2` , `etc...`

this is a very good example: [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android)

and then use  `swapAdapter` to swap the current adapter with the provided one. It is similar to `setAdapter(Adapter)` but assumes existing adapter and the new adapter uses the same `ViewHolder` and does not clear the `RecycledViewPool`.

docs:https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#swapadapter