# How we can retrieve uid user name and the uid user child value in RecyclerView in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can we access all UID users name and the UID users child value in Firebase database?

I have uploaded the pic of my database

I also use RecyclerView you tell me about Firebase query I want to retrieve data with FirestoreRecyclerOptions query :

I want to access
name of users and the amount value as shown in fig
like this

```
name:600
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all user names, of all User objects that exist under "Users" node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Because there are several objects within the "Users" node, first you need to get a reference to that node, attach a listener and then loop through the results. The result in the logcat will be:

```
jm
...
```

If you want to use the Firebase-UI library, then simply pass the "usersRef" to the FirestoreRecyclerOptions's setQuery() method, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)

Comment: is I can change android app to desktop app ?

Comment: If you learn [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/), yes you can.