# Does whereEqualTo/snapshot listener run on a background thread?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a journal app. I am trying to fetch the current users journal entries and then convert that into a journal object which will be put into a journal list. Eventually, this journal list will be sent to the RecyclerView Adapter.

I have this piece of code in `onCreate()`:

```
myCollection.whereEqualTo("userId", userId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value){
                    Journal myJournal = snapshot.toObject(Journal.class);
                    journals.add(myJournal);

                     
                    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(journals, JournalList.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(JournalList.this));
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        });
```

If I move this part:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(journals, JournalList.this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(JournalList.this));
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

out of the `onEvent` block(but still in onCreate() ), the journal is still sent to firebase, but it seems like the RecyclerViewAdapter isn't invoked until I add the second post.

My guess is that either Android Studio skips over the onEvent() block and continues on(possibly puts it in a queue considering it knows it will take time to execute), or it runs on a background thread in which the adapter part finishes first. Either way, an empty arrayList of journals is sent to Firestore.

**However, I'm unsure which one of these scenarios is actually occurring**. If someone could confirm, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Update:
Code that doesn't work:

```
myCollection.whereEqualTo("userId", userId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value){
                    Journal myJournal = snapshot.toObject(Journal.class);
                    journals.add(myJournal);



                }
            }
        });

        
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(journals, JournalList.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(JournalList.this));
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Full code of JournalList.java(if needed):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JournalList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference myCollection = db.collection("Journal");
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private List<Journal> journals;
    private Toolbar myToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal_list);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userId = currentUser.getUid();
        myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        journals = new ArrayList<>();

        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);




        myCollection.whereEqualTo("userId", userId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value){
                    Journal myJournal = snapshot.toObject(Journal.class);
                    journals.add(myJournal);



                }
            }
        });

        //my guess:
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(journals, JournalList.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(JournalList.this));
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();










    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.addNote:

                startActivity(new Intent(JournalList.this, PostJournalActivity.class));

                break;
            case R.id.sign_out:

                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(JournalList.this, MainActivity.class));

                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network request etc runs on a background thread, but the callback doesn't.

However I think your misunderstanding here comes from how callbacks work. When you pass in an `EventListener` here, you're passing in a class (in this case, an anonymous class) which overrides the `onEvent` method. There's nothing to *"skip over"* as you mentioned.

Let's consider an example. Say I defined an interface `Callback`:

```
interface Callback {

    void myMethod();
}
```

Then I can write a redundant method:

```
void doSomethingWith(Callback myCallback) {

    myCallback.myMethod();
}
```

Now here, when I call

```
doSomethingWith(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        
        // ...
    }
});

doSomethingElse();
```

the implementation of `myMethod` runs before `doSomethingElse`.

However, **it doesn't have to be this way**. Say I instead defined `doSomethingWith` like this:

```
void doSomethingWith(Callback myCallback) {

    // Do nothing
}
```

Then the code in your implementation of `myMethod` will **never** get called. Just because you passed in a class that implemented a method, doesn't guarantee when it will get called or whether it will get called at all.

To bring this back to Firebase a bit, we can consider an example like this:

```
void doSomethingWith(Callback myCallback) {

    // Switch to a background thread,
    // wait for a network request then call myCallback.myMethod()
}
```

So here your callback *will* get called, but it will be at a later time, when a network request has completed, exactly the same scenario as with your Firebase listener.

---

Now let's actually address solving your problem. It would make the most sense (to me) to declare the adapter first, then when `onEvent` is called, update the data:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(journals, JournalList.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(JournalList.this));

myCollection...addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(...) {

        myAdapter.data = ...
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

---

As a side note, Android Studio definitely doesn't play a part here, it's an IDE. Don't get Android confused with Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I'm a little confused with the String example though and how it relates to this. Can you please rephrase?  Thanks.

Comment: So is the reason the adapter block of code gets called first because they are both running simultaneously on background threads(and the adapter block finishes first)? Thanks.

Comment: In regards to my string example: the thing you've passed into `addSnapshotListener` is just a class which extends/implements `EventListener`. So say I created a class which extended a `String` and I override a method (say `substring`). Then I passed an instance of my custom string class into a method. `substring` wouldn't be called by that method, it doesn't make any sense. It would only be called if the method called it! So with this example, `onEvent` only gets called if `addSnapshotListener` calls it, which it does *after* it's finished fetching the data on a background thread.

Comment: Sorry if my string example is convoluted, if it doesn't make sense feel free to ignore it. In regards to your second question, I'm not sure exactly what you mean, what's getting called when? If your adapter code is below the `myCollection.whereEqual(...)` line then it will probably get called before `onEvent` if that's what you mean?

Comment: Hi, thanks! Even if it takes time for the snapshot listener to call `onEvent()` why would that result in problems with the journal's list(journals) for the RecyclerViewAdapter(if I call it outside of onEvent())? Thanks

Comment: I didn't intend to make it this long... But I have updated my answer so hopefully that addresses my overly-bizarre string example and your actual problem at hand. If it doesn't, let me know!

Comment: Hi, firstly, thank you so much for taking the time to write a thorough explanation. I really appreciate it. So, basically in order for onEvent() to be called, we have to invoke a callback, which will call the snapshot listener? How do we call the snapshot listener though?

Comment: How does this relate to the Recycler View Adapter being inside of onEvent(in which case everything works fine) and being outside of onEvent(in which case it doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: No problem, I think it's important to realise the simple (or not so simple!) mechanics behind this and realise it's not any Android magic etc! Not quite, in my example, the callback *is* the `EventListener`, so `onEvent` (`myMethod` in the example) gets called by Firebase whenever it's finished its network request. By calling `addSnapshotListener` you're effectively asking Firebase to do the network request, then call `onEvent` from my `EventListener` when they're ready.

Comment: Can you provide a full example of it not working with it being outside? The example I've provided with it outside should work just fine.

Comment: Hi, if I do it that way though, won't the list journals be null since I haven't populated it with the journal entries from the user in the onEvent code? Thanks. The case where it doesn't work for me which I tried is when I put the Adapter code below the ending parentheses of the whereEqualTo code

Comment: Sorry, never mind. Your way seems to work as well. Weirdly, the only way that doesn't work is putting the RecyclerAdapter code below outside of the whereEqualTo block

Comment: If you edit your question to include your example that doesn't work then I can probably tell you why!

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is because `onEvent` is called when the network request has completed, whereas `notifyDataSetChanged` is called immediately. So your list might be changing, but you're not notifying the adapter at the correct time. The order of execution would be something like this: `request data -> set adapter -> notify adapter of changes (which don't exist yet) -> ... -> data is ready (onEvent)`. Notifying the adapter obviously has to come *after* the changes come, not before.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While @Henry Twist's solution will work, please also note that you also have an alternative solution, which is the [Firebase-UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). This library does all the heavy work for you behind the scenes. You only need to start/stop listening for changes, and that's much pretty it. Please see below a working solution:

- [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the late reply. I saw this post, and told myself to get back to it, but completely forgot. This looks interesting, will definitely be sure to implement it in my future projects. Thank you!