# get int data from firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]im trying to get int data from firestore but before that app crashes i dont know why when i try it as string it work i get it and i can list it but when i try it int app crashes even before get data
here is my code second part is my adapter logchat said 2 line is wrong i mark it with stairs for u

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
ArrayList<String> useremaillist;
ArrayList<Integer> userpointlist;
SkorAdapter skorAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_skor_board);
    firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    useremaillist=new ArrayList<>();
    userpointlist=new ArrayList<>();
    getscore();
    RecyclerView skorboardrecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    skorboardrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    skorAdapter=new SkorAdapter(useremaillist,userpointlist);
    skorboardrecyclerView.setAdapter(skorAdapter);

}
public void getscore(){
    CollectionReference collectionReference=firestore.collection("Kullanıcılar ve Skorlar");
    collectionReference.orderBy("skor", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable  QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable  FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            userpointlist.clear();
            useremaillist.clear();
            if(error!=null){
                Log.e("tag",error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            if(value!=null){
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                    Map<String,Object> userdatat=snapshot.getData();
                    String emailt=(String) userdatat.get("email");
                    int skor=(int) userdatat.get("skor");
                    useremaillist.add(emailt);
                    userpointlist.add(skor);
                    skorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }

    });

}

  **   public class SkorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SkorAdapter.Holder> {
private ArrayList<String> emaillistforadapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> pointlistforadapter;


public SkorAdapter(ArrayList<String> emaillistforadapter,ArrayList<Integer> pointlistforadapter ) {
    this.emaillistforadapter = emaillistforadapter;
    this.pointlistforadapter = pointlistforadapter;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull  ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.skorboard_row,parent,false);
    return new Holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  SkorAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.useremailtext.setText(emaillistforadapter.get(position));
  **    holder.userpointtext.setText(pointlistforadapter.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return emaillistforadapter.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView useremailtext;
    TextView userpointtext;
    public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        useremailtext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.kullanıcımailtext);
        userpointtext=itemView.findViewById(R.id.kullanıcıpointtext);

    }


}
```

Comment: post your logcat error and firebase structure

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran i add my firebase up side and the errors in the 2 lines on the adapter thats what logchat said i marked it with stairs.Thanks

Comment: please follow this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49277842/12709358

Comment: i can list emails when i remove score my problem is int value not this when i saves score as string i can list it to

Comment: convert int to string then use it ,

Comment: it crashes again log said the convert is the problem i dont think it will work that way but thanks.

Comment: ```String tmp = String.valueOf(skor);``` use this line

Comment: that didnt work but someone answered it in the bottom thank you for trying to help.

Comment: super go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the adapter then.

You have a `private ArrayList<Integer> pointlistforadapter;` and the problem is that you are doing  `holder.userpointtext.setText(pointlistforadapter.get(position));` and [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) accepts a `CharSeq` and it lets you add an `Int` in paramter because it also has this signature :

[image]

And since it's not a resid it crashes.

What you can do is :

```
holder.userpointtext.setText(pointlistforadapter.get(position).toString());
```

Comment: i would really want to do it but because of im new i cant how unfortunately i need 15 reputation system said