# How can i retrieve values of Firebase Nodes with random auto generated IDs in Android Using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know how to go about retrieving data from the Firebase Realtime Database where the values have randomly generated IDs as seen below.
[image]

Comment: Which node are you trying to fetch ?

Comment: The nodes under 21-6-2021 which is under CSC101

Comment: Any Idea please? Dharmaraj.

Comment: If you don't know the random keys then you would have to know something about it's content. For example in your users node, even if you don't know user's UID, you can still find it by their email. Checkout [querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries)

Comment: So can you query those values with current user's email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to get all the keys and values that exist under the `21-6-21` node, you need to loop through the DatasnaShot object, as in the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val dateRef = rootRef.child("SigninData").child("CSC101").child("21-6-21")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val key = ds.getkey()
            val value = ds.getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", "$key/$value")
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
-Mf8...ESM/oma@gmail.com...
-Mf8...7nb/oma@gmail.com...
-Mf8...XJv/oma@gmail.com...
```

**Edit:**

```
private fun getDataFrom(date: String) {
    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val dateRef = rootRef.child("SigninData").child("CSC101").child(date)
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val key = ds.getkey()
                val value = ds.getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.d("TAG", "$key/$value")
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
    dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
}
```

Now you can call the above method either with:

```
getDataFrom("21-6-21")
```

Or:

```
getDataFrom("22-6-21")
```

If you need to get them both, then you should use a get() call, and pass both Task objects to the [whenAllSuccess(Task...<?> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)).

Comment: Good morning Alex, I'll try this once I get power    on my computer, thank you for your response.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works ;)

Comment: Thank you Alex, it prints to the logcat, is there a way I can query to retrieve those values with the date nodes, like when I enter 21-6-2021 I'll get the data under it, and when I enter 22-6-2021 I get the data under it too?

Comment: Good to hear that it prints the right value in the logcat. Yes, you can. So please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex, I'll get back to you when I try the Edit.

Comment: can i replace the .child(date) with variable say .child("$date") where date will be value of a textview, so that as the database increases, one can search for any day of the week

Comment: No, you cannot do that in Kotlin. You can only call the function, once, with one, or the other argument.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a native speaker of the English language, so my tenses may not be right, what I mean up there was, to receive data from an EditText, not Textview then the variable holding the EditText value is 'date', so you can now call it in the .child("") path as $date, fortunately, it worked, I can search through CSC101, given that the date supplied matches the date in the database.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, that's certainly possible. Good to hear you made it work.

Comment: Nice to know, thank you @Alex for your response.

Comment: is there any way I can place these values in a recyclerView or listView, I've searched all I can, but no success, to display those data on the list or recyclerview is the last part of my project please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235229/discussion-between-oriohac-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842) out.

Comment: I've checked it, seemed confusing, I don't know much about Firestore

Comment: Try to implement it, and if have a hard time to make it work, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work out for you.

```
    fun getDataFromFirebaseDatabase() {
        // Your path 
        database.getReference("SigninData/CSC101/21-6-21")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                //this checks if there were any exceptions or Errors generated and will Log the error in your Logcat.
                if (it.exception != null) Log.e("FirebaseDatabase", "Error", it.exception)
                // this checks if your result was successful or not and also, 
                //if it has children or not, if both conditions are satisfied,
                //it will enter the for loop and print all the
                // values along with their keys in logcat.
                if (it.isSuccessful && it.result.hasChildren()) {
                    for (i in it.result.children) {
                        //i.key will give you required key
                        Log.d("FirebaseDatabase", "key is ${i.key}")
                        // i.value will give respective value
                        // import the values as given in database, for your case it would be String so.
                        val data = i.value as String
                        Log.d("FirebaseDatabase", "value is $data")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

**Note - This will read all the values inside 21-6-21 child**

Your Logcat should look something like this.

```
//if there is an error
E/FirebaseDatabase: Error <Some Error Code Here>

//if Run is Successful
//since there are 3 entries in CSC101 node all three will be printed one by one
//like the example given below

D/FirebaseDatabase: key is Mf80wSd9neOAqlPhESM
D/FirebaseDatabase: value is oma@gmail.com You signed in for CSC101
```

The above code uses **get()** function which means your app will only read the database only once.
Instead of get() you can also use:

1. addChildEventListener()
2. addValueEventListener()
3. addListenerForSingleValueEvent()

All are for different purposes.
Here are the Firebase Docs regarding these: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data

the 3rd one is similar to the get function but 3rd one will read from the cache memory and should be used when you are not expecting your data to change frequently.

1st and 2nd will get the results from the database as soon as there are changes made in the database nodes.

Comment: Let me try this out, I'll get back to you if I can use it and retrieve data on my listView

Comment: lets start coding, i tried out the code, but still not working the getReference() says 'unresolved getReference'. When I called it in an onClickListener(){}

Comment: @oriohac I believe the problem is with the reference I have provided try removing your project name and change the reference to "SigninData/CSC101/21-6-21"

Comment: @oriohac Also, can you post the error message here

Comment: Please what do I expect to see in my logcat if the code is working?

Comment: @oriohac I have edited my answer and is more detailed, my answer tells you how to use get function while Alex answer tells you how to use valueEventListener, if you want regular and frequent updates to use valueEventListener. If you want more detailed updates use childEventListener whereas if you want updates only once use either the get() function or SingleValueEvent as per your needs

Comment: Alright i tried it out, but i still got an Error: 'I/RepoOperation: get for query /SigninData/CSC101/21-6-2021 falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline'