# How to create category containing products in firestore firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore to make my own E-commerce App. I want my category collection to contain many categories like shoes, clothes, watches, etc and in each of those categories there are different products so I can click on that category and show all the related products on my app, please guide me or if you have another way to do this, please show me.

[Category and Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBM0N.png)

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: I don't really know, this is my first time I using nosql and firestore... Can you give me the solution in your way?

Comment: Without knowing the exact queries you want to perform it's hard to help. I can only make an assumption, but not sure if it will help.

Comment: I just want in a collection to have many different categories and in each category I will add related products from another collections as you can see in the picture, so that my app will show all the categories and I can click on that particular category to show all those products.

Comment: How many categories will you have? Tens, hundreds, thousnds?

Comment: Your current structure is fine for your use case just put the category document Id as a field in the individual product's document.

Comment: @AlexMamo just tens, this is just my personal project.

Comment: @HarisWilson Should I create multiple category documents in a collection named Category and put the product ids inside that related document?

Comment: If you're new to using Firestore and NoSQL databases in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> just tens, this is just my personal project.

Since you only have tens of category names, then the best option that you have is to store them in a **single** document, in an array type field. Then each product document should contain a field where you have to specify the category. Your schema should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- shop (collection)
  |    |
  |    --- category (document)
  |          |
  |          --- names: ["shoes", "clothes", "watches"]
  |
  --- products (collection)
       |
       --- $productId (document)
             |
             --- name: "Nike Air Jordan"
             |
             --- category: "shoes"
```

To be able to display the category names, you should simply read the array that exists in the document, and display the content into a ListView, or even better, in a RecyclerView.

Furthermore, if you need to click on a particular category, and go forward to display only the products that correspond to a specific category, then you should use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query queryByCategory = db.collection("products").whereEqualTo("category", "shoes");
```

For displaying the products you might consider reading my answer from the following post:

> [How to display data from Firestore in a RecyclerView with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277797/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-in-a-recyclerview-with-android/49277842)

The following article might also help you read the data with the use of the Firebase-UI library:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

Comment: Your answer is very clear, but what if the amount of data is in the hundreds, thousands like you said then what would be the best data structure according to you? I would love to hear from you.

Comment: It will work with hundreds, or even thousands, but always be aware of the maximum limitation of the document which is **1 Mib**. If you think that you can get over this limitation, then you should consider creating another document. Using this solution, you'll always keep bills at a minimum.

Comment: Any other information?

Comment: I don't have any more problems at the moment but in the future there will be :( asking on stack overflow is quite inconvenient because there are quite a few answers.